# ruby flatten and compact array full of empty arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, flatten

In my ruby project, I have an array of arrays of arrays which is the result of doing some heavy graph traversal

example:

```
[[], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [[], [], [[], [], [34, 54, 23, 45]]]]
```

I want the final product to be

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [34, 54, 23, 45]]
```

flatten will leave me with

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34, 54, 23, 45]
```

so I don't want that

I'm stuck and could use some help on how to do this

so far, I have

```
class Array
  def flatten_blanks
    each{ |elem| elem.flatten_blanks if elem.is_a?(Array) }
    reject!{ |elem| elem.is_a?(Array) && elem.length < 1 }
    self
  end
end
```

which is close but leaves me with something like

```
[[[[[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]]]]], [[[[[[[34, 54, 23, 45]]]]]]]
```

Comment: Could your graph traversal algorithm also leave you with an array like `[[],[1,2,[3,4]]]`, and if yes, what would be the desired result? If this can not happen, i.e. if each subarray is either empty, or consists only of non-array elements, or consists only of elements which are arrays as well, you could just recursively traverse your array and collect those subarrays `subarr`, where `subarr.first.class` is neither `NilClass` nor `Array`.

Answer (score 9):

```
squeeze = -> (arr, acc = []) do
  case arr.compact.first
  when NilClass then acc
  when Array
    arr.reject(&:empty?).map { |e| squeeze.(e, acc) }.first
  else acc << arr
  end
end
squeeze.(arr)
#⇒ [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [34, 54, 23, 45]]
```

Comment: only caveat is if the sub `Array` contains `nil` as a first element the whole `Array` will be rejected.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, indeed. I will add compact.

Answer (score 2):

For you example it does the trick:

```
array = [[], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [[], [], [[], [], [34, 54, 23, 45]]]]
array.map(&:flatten).delete_if(&:empty?)
```

It will produce:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [34, 54, 23, 45]]
```

Comment: It won’t work if any nested array has at least two non-empty elements. I wonder who had this upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'json'

arr = [[], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [[], [], [[], [], [34, 54, 23, 45]]]]

JSON.parse("[#{arr.to_json.scan(/\[[^\[\]]+\]/).join(',')}]")
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [34, 54, 23, 45]]
```

A recursive method (similar to mudsie's recursive proc) could also be used.

```
def recurse(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) { |e,a|
    e.first.is_a?(Array) ? a.concat(recurse e) : a << e unless e.empty? }
end

recurse(arr)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [34, 54, 23, 45]]
```

Comment: Great. I thought about abusing json, but failed to come up with such an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your array arr

```
arr.map(&:flatten).reject(&:empty?)
```

To explain a little, you run flatten on the array's elements instead of the array itself, and then delete the empty subarrays.